# Dividing points and polyline into segments in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, distance, splitting, segment

I have a question about measuring distances for points in separate segments. As you can see in the attached picture, the green line is my polyline which I want to divide into four segments A, B,C,D. I want to measure the distance of each point in a particular segment to the polyline. I don't want the distance to overlap in the sense that a point in segment A should not take its measurement in segment B or C or D. A point in segment A, for example, should take its measurement at any place on the polyline that falls in segment A only.
I must add that the the points and the polyline are separate features. Also, the red lines are just to show you how I want my segments to be.
So first of all, I want to know how I can divide the polyline and the points into segments. Then I want to measure the distance of each point in a particular segment to the polyline.
Just to remind that, the polyline and the points are two separate features.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap 10.8)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your line anyway you choose! If you are looking for a tool may be this one on [ESRI code sharing](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d5d27ee47330434b9a96b91136a0118f) can help?

You can use the Near Tool to generate the distances from the polyline.

But you show a single polyline going North to south and give no indication of how many lines you intend to process and the number of points? Is it hundreds of millions or just what you are showing? Then what about direction of line what if it is curved say like the letter S but going east to west?

You need to be much clearer in your rule set and the types of scenarios that will be encountered.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks.

Comment: The lines will be 3 straight lines running from east to west. there's just one polyline. but the number of points are many.